# move to the next row after case is found

Tags: php, foreach, while-loop

I'm trying to split al the ip's in the database into different arrays based on country, so far i've got this. Now its only taking the first IP of the results out of the query which leads to all the results being the same but i want to get every time a IP got played to move to the next one.

I've tried to use a for loop   but that didn't work either since it gave me over 550 results but there are only 24 rows in this test DB.

What is a good way to do this? I think it still should be a for each or something like that but i didnt find the right solution yet.

```
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$NL = array('');
$AL = array('');
$DE = array('');
$NO_EU = array('');

$row=$result_ip->fetch_assoc();// fetch data
$ip=$row['ip'];
$details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
$result_ip->data_seek(0);
while($r = $result_ip->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)):

switch ($details->country) {
    case "NL": //Netherlands
        array_push($NL,"$details->country");
        break;
    case "AL":  //Albania
        array_push($AL,"$details->country");
        break;
   default;
       array_push($NO_EU,"no-eu");
    break;
}
endwhile;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd make a single array keyed by country using a `foreach` loop over the DB results. Something like:

```
<?php
$result_ip = $dbhandle->query("SELECT ip FROM email");
$row_cnt_ip = $result_ip->num_rows;
$ip_rows = $result_ip->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$country_ip_data = array();

foreach ($ip_rows as $ip_row) {
    $ip = $ip_row['ip'];
    if (!$ip) {
        continue;
    }
    $details = json_decode(file_get_contents("http://ipinfo.io/{$ip}"));
    $country = $details->country;
    if (!isset($country_ip_data[$country])) {
        $country_ip_data[$country] = array();
    }
    $country_ip_data[$country][] = $ip;
}

var_dump($country_ip_data);
```

Comment: the result of the vardump is array(1) { [""]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "8" } } and i also get a warning: Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io/8): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found in. It looks like its only using the first number in of the IP.

Comment: object(mysqli_result)#19 (5) { ["current_field"]=> int(0) ["field_count"]=> int(1) ["lengths"]=> array(1) { [0]=> int(12) } ["num_rows"]=> int(24) ["type"]=> int(0) } there should be 24 rows and contain 12 numbers/dots in every row so i dont understand why its only trying to get ipinfo.oi/8

Comment: Thanks i've found out already but this answer really helped me out

Comment: Good to hear :) Thanks for coming back to accept it anyway.